# Error with a method that calls another function

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

I got a mysterious error-message in swift, xcode:

The following code has an error at the line with `somethingElse(p)` that says "Use of unresolved identifier 'somethingElse'".

```
enum symbol: Int {
    case x = 1
    case o = 2
}

class player {
    var p: symbole

    init(p: symbol) {
        self.p = symbol
    }

    func something() {
        somethingElse(p)
    }
}
```

but when I called the method and worked with it like

```
func somethingElse(p: symbol) {
    bla = p
}


var test = player(p: .x)
test.something()
bla
```

the error-message still appears, but everything works fine.

Comment: You defined an enum as `symbol` not `symbole`

Comment: ur right, thanks. But that came with copying (and anonymise) the code to stack overflow...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... Calling a method that isn't defined is an error. I assume this isn't surprising to you so what are you asking?

Comment: but the method is defined(?). What do you miss?

Comment: The posted code is *not* what you put in the playground. Please post the code you put in the playground and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles fine:

```
enum symbol: Int {
    case x = 1
    case o = 2
}

class player {
    var p: symbol

    init(p: symbol) {
        self.p = p
    }

    func something() {
        somethingElse(p)
    }
}

func somethingElse(p: symbol) {
    //bla = p
}

var test = player(p: .x)
test.something()
//bla
```